# Having Ubuntu and iPhone talk over WiFi

Tags: 14.04, networking, iphone

I am looking to make a system where I have an ubuntu computer running, connected to my home wifi network, which can receive messages from an iphone connected to the same wifi network.  My plan is to make buttons on an iphone app I build to trigger commands on the ubuntu computer.  In a nutshell, I am looking to build a home system where if I connect my iphone to my home wifi, I can control certain commands in an application on my ubuntu computer.

Is it possible for an iphone and ubuntu computer on the same wireless network to communicate?  I do not want to send these messages over the internet; I want to use just my wifi network.  If it is possible, what technologies should I look into to have the ubuntu computer and iphone to talk?

Example:  a simple implementation of my idea would be to create a music player, where the ubuntu computer has the speakers and music library, and when I connect to my wifi on my iphone, I can play songs on the ubuntu computer from my iphone.

This is more of a concept question than a technical question, so if this is not the proper place to ask this question, please let me know the proper stack exchange site to use.

Comment: I was thinking about something similar, just with Android phone. Hope for some good answers.

Comment: @NonStandardModel for Android there are many options already. dan, maybe you can have a look at which of these options for Android are open source and try to port them to the iPhone.

Comment: It would have to involve SSH I think. Maybe even a jailbroken iPhone.